# How to prevent scrolling FlatList when the top is reached in react native

Tags: react-native

> I am new to React Native framework, I want to prevent scrolling
>   FlatList when the top is reached in iOS platform like FlatList in
>   Android platform does. I have been searching for solution but still
>   not solve this. Please help me :(

Never mind guys, I have solve this by setting the props bounces to false :D

Comment: Try to add `alwaysBounceVertical={false}` to your flatlist

Comment: @Théodvn hi, thanks for your answer, but it still scrolls when the top is reached :(

Comment: @Théodvn Hi, I just solve this problem, thank you once again :D